# Does storing a returned reference into a variable allow you to access that variable?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I am confused as to why storing a reference to a member variable with an alias allows us to access it, while storing it with a variable does not allow us to access the same variable.

Let me clear up what I mean, say we have class Journey:

```
class Journey {
  protected:
      Coordinate start; //coordinate consists of x and y values
  public:
      Journey(Coordinate startIn,): start(startIn){} 
  //methods ......
  Coordinate & getStart(){ //returns a reference to the "start" member
    return start; 
  }
};
```

- now say I do this

```
int main() {
    Journey j(Coordinate(1,1));
    Coordinate & a = j.getStart();  //function returns a reference and is stored under the alias "a"
    a.setX(0); //changes X value of the "start" member variable
    cout << j.getStart().getX() << endl; //returns 0 - as expected!
}
```

- the example above works as I returned a reference to the member variable "start" and stored it under an alias and I accessed it to change the original member variable
- **But** say I stored the reference to start under a variable instead

```
int main() {
    Journey j(Coordinate(1,1));
    Coordinate a = j.getStart();  //function returns a reference and is stored under the VARIABLE "a"
    a.setX(0); 
    cout << j.getStart().getX() << endl; //returns 1 - Original start was not changed?
}
```

- I cannot do the same as a does not access the start member variable

I am not sure why this happens? What happened behind the scenes? We are storing the reference to start under a **variable** instead of an **alias**.

Comment: In the context of *variables*, the term **alias** is jargon for **reference**.  In the context of *types*, a **typedef** or a **using** is a type alias.

Comment: Think of a reference as *another name* for the same object. (Another word for "another name" is "alias", but "another name" expresses clearly what it is.) The implementation of a reference is probably with a pointer to the object; everything you can do with references you could do with pointers, except that you would need more `*`s...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are calling a copy constructor when instantiating a `Coordinate` object with `Coordinate a = j.getStart()`. That is, `Coordinate a` is a *copy* of `start`, not a reference to it. Read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) about copy constructors.

As for the question in the title, no, it doesn't. If you want some identifier to be a reference, you need to define it as a reference as you did in the first case.

Answer (score 0):

A reference is an alias for a variable.

In your first example, `a` is a reference, and by construction, it aliases `j.start`.

In your second example, `a` is not a reference and does not alias anything. How it is initialised (with a reference or otherwise) is irrelevant.